# .Net Scenario Based Opinion

Tags: asp.net, wpf, xml

I am facing a situation where I am stuck in a very heavy traffic load and keeping the performance high at the same time. Here is my scenario, please read it and advise me with your valuable opinion.

I am going to have a three way communication between my server, client and visitor. When visitor visits my client's website, he will be detected and sent to a intermediate Rule Engine to perform some tasks and output a filtered list of different visitors on my server. On the other side, I have a client who will access those lists. Now what my initial idea was to have a Web Service at my server who will act as a Rule Engine and output resultant lists on an ASPX page. But this seems to be inefficient because there will be huge traffic coming in and the clients will continuously requesting data from those lists so it will be a performance overhead. Kindly suggest me what approach should I do to achieve this scenario so that no deadlock will happen and things work smoothly. I also considered the option for writing and fetching from XML file but its also not very good approach in my case.

NOTE: Please remember that no DB will involve initially, all work will remain outside DB.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, storing data efficiently without a database will be tricky. What you can possibly consider is the following:

1. Store the visitor data in an object list of some sort and keep it in the application cache on the server.
2. Periodically flush this list (say after 100 items in the list) to a file on the server - possibly storing it in XML for ease of access (you can associate a schema with it as well to make sure you always get the same structure you need). You can perform this file-writing asynchronously as to avoid keeping the thread locked while writing the file.
3. The Web Service sounds like a good idea - make it feed off the XML file. Possibly consider breaking the XML file up into several files as well. You can even cache the contents of this file separately so the service feeds of the cached data for added performance benefits...

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply. I like your ideas but I am already considering them and they seems not very efficient in my case because either List on XML, both are being writing and fetching at the same time which may cause a deadlock or crash situation so I am avoiding this. May be any other medium which perfectly works for this scenario ?

Comment: You can split up the XML file into seperate sections, date-stamping each flush perhaps and only reading from the finalized file(s). So you'll never writing to a file that's being read, as each flush will have a new file... So in essence, you have another file each hour, with perhaps a service of sorts combining them during off-peak hours?

Comment: ok cool let me discuss this idea with my mates and will get back to you :) Thanks anyway!

Comment: Pleasure! Hope it guides you to a feasible answer... Obviously I don't know of all the complexities involved in your application, but off hand this is what I would suggest. Prototype the idea, do some load testing on it and see how it goes.